# Update list element when list is a dictionary's value in python

Tags: python-3.x

Could you help me to update a specific element of a list when this list is a dictionary's value?
Pattern: schema = {'name': ('newname', 'type', 'newtype')}
For example:

```
schema = {'foo': ('foo', 'text', 'text')}
Should give:
schema = {'foo': ('newfoo', 'text', 'boolean')}
```

I can access value with (for example):

```
schema['foo'][2]
```

But can't assign new value because schema is a tuple

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp), tuples are unchangeable. If you want to update the values, you should use an actual list [].

```
schema = {'foo': ['foo', 'text', 'text']}
```